# Wright Omega function: how to interpret the solution?

Tags: special-functions, lambert-w

I gotta solve
\begin{align}
(\ln(ab) - ab + c)\left(\frac{1}{a} - b\right) = 0
\end{align}
for $a$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_+$.
We clearly have a solution at $a = \frac{1}{b}$. However, Matlab tells me that we also have  `a = -wrightOmega(- c - pi*1i)/b`. No idea what I should make of it.

- Can I neglect the second solution due to the fact, that $a$ is supposed to be real?

Comment: For most values of $c$, no solution $x$ to $\log x - x + c = 0$ has a closed-form expression. Note, though, that there are no real solutions when $c < 1$.

Comment: @clueless: If the answer below was helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: By the way, if you need to evaluate your Wright omega function numerically (and faster than with Matlab's  `wrightOmega`), you might find [my implementation here](https://github.com/horchler/wrightOmegaq) helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution, is as you correctly note:

$$a=\frac{1}{b}$$

The second equation can be solved in terms of the Lambert $W$ function, as:

$$
\begin{align}
\ln(ab)-ab+c&=0\Rightarrow\\
\ln(ab)&=ab-c\Rightarrow\text{ (pass through $\exp$)}\\
ab&=e^{ab}\cdot e^{-c}\Rightarrow\\
ab\cdot e^{-ab}&=e^{-c}\Rightarrow\\
-ab\cdot e^{-ab}&=-e^{-c}\Rightarrow\\
-ab&=W_k(-e^{-c})\Rightarrow\\
a&=\frac{-W_k(-e^{-c})}{b}\text{,  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now, the Wright-Omega function $\omega$ satisfies:

$$W_k(z)=\omega(\ln(z)+2k\pi i)\text{,  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}$$

Therefore you can express the solutions in terms of this function as:

$$a=\frac{-\omega(\ln(-e^{-c})+2k\pi i)}{b}\text{,  $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}$$

Choosing the principal branch of $\ln$ and for the particular case where $c\ge 1$ the branch of $W$ which gives real solutions, is the $k=-1$ branch, so:

$$
\begin{align}
a&=\frac{-W_{-1}(-e^{-c})}{b}\Rightarrow\\
a&=\frac{-\omega(\ln(-e^{-c})+2(-1)\pi i)}{b}\Rightarrow\\
a&=\frac{-\omega(\pi i -c - 2\pi i)}{b}\Rightarrow\\
a&=\frac{-\omega(-c -\pi i)}{b}
\end{align}
$$